# Windows cmd.exe not showing actual php version

Tags: php

Recently i have installed **xampp** update version which have php 5.6 version. In my c drive i have older version of xampp, i renamed it by xampp_old. My new xampp installation files in C:\xampp. When i try to get php version by my cmd.exe by `php -v` command it show older php version (php 5.4.24).I have checked my cmd uses the `C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v5.4\php.ini` file. How can i set the new php.ini file for my cmd.exe from the `c:\xampp\php`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the php command in the c:\xampp folder. If it's still showing the old version, replace the path in your System Environment Variables.

1. Start -> type: Edit the system environment variables
2. Click Environment variables (lower right corner)
3. Under system variables -> Select and edit PATH
4. Replace the old folder or add *c:\xampp\php;* in the Variable value field

Comment: i have changed my environment variable path c:\xampp\php. Now it's working.